# JavaFX - avoid blur when drawing with rect on Canvas with highdpi

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, blur, highdpi

I'd like to draw on a JavaFX Canvas. Coordinates for the canvas are provided by double values, but I understand that in order to "snap" to the pixel grid, I need integer numbers to avoid drawing "inbetween" pixels, which will result in a blur/smoothing on edges.

Consider this minimal example:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        var vbox = new VBox();
        var canvas = new Canvas(600, 400);
        var gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // draw a background
        gc.beginPath();
        gc.setFill(Color.rgb(200,200,200));
        gc.rect(0, 0, 600, 400);
        gc.fill();

        // draw a smaller square
        gc.beginPath();
        gc.setFill(Color.rgb(100,100,100));
        gc.rect(9.0, 9.0, 50, 50);  // snap to grid
        gc.fill();

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(canvas);

        var scene = new Scene(vbox, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

This works and will result in a clear edge, consider this image:

[image]

Now suppose HighDPI is enabled, i.e. consider if we scale graphics in Windows 10 to 125 percent. This will result in a scale factor of 1.25 (we can obtain this via getOutputScaleX/Y).

However then the whole canvas is scaled with that factor, and we get a blur. See the attached images (but you have to zoom, and maybe view them in a graphics program and not in a browser).

[image]

Then I thought that we can adjust the original coordinates such that the scaled coordinates will result in integers. For example to make sure we hit an integer with offset 9 * 1.25 = 11.25 on the scaled image, let's try to target 11.0 instead, i.e. change this line

```
gc.rect(9.0, 9.0, 50, 50);
```

to

```
gc.rect(11.0/1.25, 11.0/1.25, 50, 50);
```

But this *still* results in a blur at the edge.

How can we work around this? Ideally I would like to turn off dpi scaling completely for the canvas, and do my own (pixel-perfect) calculations. Is this possible or is there any other solution?

For drawImage there is a parameter setSmoothing, but there is nothing when drawing shapes directly (like rect).

Comment: What values do the getRenderScaleX/Y methods return in your case in contrast to the getOutputScaleX/Y.

Comment: What is this `HighDPI` option you are talking about?  Did you tweak any options that windows offers for executables, like the high DPI settings or compatibility modes?  Because you shouldn't need to do that for JavaFX, it is high dpi aware.

Comment: Windows Settings app  -> System -> Display -> Scale and layout section -> Change the size of text, apps, and other icons. This actually changs the dpi setting in Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by eliminating the scaling used by scaling the Canvas to a smaller size.  Here is a sample (note that lines are drawn "in between" pixels in JavaFX, so to get them sharp you need to add 0.5).

This example also places a `Group` around the scaled `Canvas`.  This is required to take the scale into account when doing layout, but also has some effect on rendering.  This example was tested at 100%, 125% and 150%.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CanvasTest extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    HBox hbox = new HBox();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(100,100);

    GraphicsContext g2d = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    g2d.fillRect(15, 15, 60, 10);
    g2d.fillRect(15.5, 30, 60, 10);  // supposed to be blurry
    g2d.fillRect(16, 45, 60, 10);
    g2d.fillRect(16.5, 60, 60, 10);  // supposed to be blurry

    g2d.setStroke(Color.RED);
    g2d.strokeLine(13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 93.5);
    g2d.strokeLine(13.5, 13.5, 93.5, 93.5);
    hbox.getChildren().add(new Group(canvas));

    Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    canvas.scaleXProperty().bind(new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0).divide(scene.getWindow().outputScaleXProperty()));
    canvas.scaleYProperty().bind(new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0).divide(scene.getWindow().outputScaleYProperty()));
  }
}
```

Here is how it looks on a 150% monitor (left side is scaled up 5 times so you can see there is no blur):

[image]

And here is how it looks at 125% with the updated example:

[image]

Comment: I have a 1920*1080 screen. If I run your example at 150% scaling, there is no blur. However at 125%, there is one pixel-line of gray blur around the black rectangle.

Comment: Hm, what version of JavaFX?  I was using 11.0.1.  For me, the above example works flawlessly, even when I drag the window from a 100% screen to a 150% screen, it is immediately redrawn.  Without the OutputScale listeners I get blurry results.  Maybe you can print the values of OutputScaleX/Y and see if they change.  For a 4k screen (3840x2160) I get output scale of 2560x1440 at 150%.

Comment: as said, no problem @150% scaling, only at 125% scaling. I suspect an issue with certain fractions. Java version here is 11.0.6; outputScaleX/Y @125% is obviously 1.25, and 1.50 @ 150%.

Comment: Strangely, at 125%, drawing the rect at +0.5 pixel offsets (`fillRect(15.5, 15.5, 60, 60)`) removes this blur completely.  It does start to sound like a bug.

Comment: Adding a translate to the canvas of +0.5 also solves the issue when it is at 125%.  Perhaps making these adjustment configurable per scaling factor would be a satisfactory solution for now.

Comment: I found this issue which has a similar problem with 125% scaling (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8220484).  It's not exactly the same, but it could be a similar issue here where the difference between `Math.round` and `Math.ceil` matters and the wrong one was used.  I did a quick grep through the JFX code base, but couldn't find anything obvious `OutputScale` related that might cause what we're both seeing here.  Might be worth filing an issue for.

Comment: I was unable to file a bug at bugs.openjdk.java.net - there is a login screen, but nowhere to register. openjfx.io also has no links to any kind of bug tracking system. In the end I filed a bug at bugs.java.com, but I guess that one will be closed as JavaFX is not part of the JDK anymore... Let's see if anything comes out of this...

Comment: That should be fine, it is not part of the JDK, but still maintained by Oracle.  If not, I'll file it.

Comment: Was looking into this a bit further, and after tweaking the size of the canvas a bit, I couldn't reproduce this anymore on my 125% screen.  I think I may now have found a way to solve this issue.  I've updated the example, but now with a `Group` added around the scaled canvas.  This for some reason solves the problem at 125%.  What I'm guessing is that the Canvas, after scaling without a group around it, wasn't rendered (as a whole) on an exact pixel boundary.  With a group around it however it now works.  Please check this out :)

Comment: Adding the group around indeed solves the problem. Thanks very much for diving into this.I've accepted your answer. Cf. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8247541 .